# I'm trying to import CSV file using pandas, But I'm getting Error

Tags: pandas

```
C:\Users\Misti\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Misti/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Misti/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv('milestone2.csv')
  File "C:\Users\Misti\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Misti\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 586, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Misti\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 482, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Misti\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 811, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\Misti\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1040, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
  File "C:\Users\Misti\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 69, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(self.handles.handle, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 549, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and then [edit] your question to well, include the relevant parts of your source code. Remember that people here ONLY have the information YOU give to us. How do think we can help you with your code when you arent sharing your code?

Comment: and are you SURE your .csv file contains actual valid CSV data?

Comment: Sorry for providing incomplete information. Thanks for your help ,my issue is resolved

Comment: You are welcome. Basically you have two options now: if you think your problem is something that might be of interest to other people, then please enhance your question to include the relevant parts to *identify* the problem. Then write a self answer and explain how you solved it. If you think it isn't worth the effort, then simply consider to delete your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.